# How to prevent Eclipse formatter from inserting spaces at the beginning of line comment

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-formatter

The Eclipse formatter inserts a space before the content of line comments like this:

```
//foo bar

turns into

// foo bar
```

How can I stop this? No option I found in eclipse seems to disable this behavior. (apart from completely disabling line comment formatting which I don't want to do because line wrapping is still helpful)

Comment: that doesn't get rid of the extra space added between `//` and the comment content

Comment: version 2018-09. As far as I have observed that setting doesn't affect the space between the prefix and the content but rather if comments that have no indentation before them at all are even considered for formatting. Given that my comments are at varying levels of indentation and none without any indentation, I can't see how this will help me.

Comment: By unchecking "Enable line comment formatting" you are disabling formatting for all line comments which I explicitly stated that I wanted to avoid doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A distinct non answer: don't fight tooling.

I have never seen comments without that initial space, so my conclusion is: eclipse is not offering an option for this case because "nobody" needs that feature.

Especially when writing code, you have to balance your personal "preference" versus "what everyone does". Meanung: when 99 of 100 coders find your style strange and surprising, then it might be better for you to do what the other 99 people do. Or, as they say: when you are in Rome, do as the Romans do!

Comment: right, so adding spaces before comments in Java code is so widespread that there is no option to change this? I don't do a lot of Java and in other languages (like JS) I know there is usually an option for this.

Comment: @douira I can't point to an official coding style guide right now (might add that next week). I am mainly talking from personal experience, and reading Java code for 20 years and the initial gut feeling is: that space should be there and not be omitted.

Comment: In fact, there's no option on formatter setting to change that. `Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter` allows to change several things, but not that one.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz true. But in the end, the formatter is controlled by some corresponding XML, so theoretically, there might be an undocumented flag to enable the desired behavior. But then my argument still holds.